# Only one item displaying in a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel

I am currently making a point system for my school that draws data from a database and displays it in a DataPanel, a subclass of JPanel, which is filled with Student classes which are each individual cells. This is also a subclass of JPanel. The reason why I do not use JTable is because it does not please my aesthetic needs. Anyway, it works fine when I just add the Student classes into the DataPanel, however, when I try to add a JCheckBox by making a parent JPanel which has the layout BorderLayout and add the checkbox on the West, and the Student on the Center, it only displays one cell even though the DataPanel's size should accommodate all of the data in the database. Here are some pictures and code:

[image]

[image]

And here is the code for the DataPanel class:

```
class DataPanel extends JPanel{
static Student[] students;
public DataPanel(String[][] data) {
    try{setLayout(new GridLayout(data.length,1));} catch(Exception e) { 
        GUI.control.updateUI();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The search criteria you have entered is incorrect and did not generate any outcome.", "Invalid Search Criteria", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(382,data.length*20));
    students = new Student[data.length-1];
    JPanel parent = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        Student contents = new Student();
        JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[4];
        for(int x = 0; x < data[0].length; x++) {
            JLabel cur = new JLabel(" "+data[i][x]);
            cur.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN,12));
            labels[x] = cur;
            //System.out.println(data[0].length);

            contents.add(cur);

        }

        contents.setId(labels[0]);
        contents.setName(labels[1]);
        contents.setForm(labels[2]);
        contents.setPoints(labels[3]);
        contents.setParent(parent);
        JCheckBox box = new JCheckBox();

        contents.setCheckBox(box);

        parent.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.lightGray));
        parent.add("Center", contents);
        parent.add("West", box);
        add(contents); // >> parent = only one showing?
        System.out.println(i);
        if(i == 0) {
            parent.setBackground(new Color(200,200,255));
        }
        if(i != 0) {
            students[i-1] = contents;
        }
    }
}

public static void refresh() {
    for(Student i: students) {
        if(i != Student.getSelected()) {
        i.setBackground(Color.white); 
        }
    }

}
```

}

and Student class:

```
class Student extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
JLabel name;
JLabel id;
JLabel points;
JLabel form;
JCheckBox box;
JPanel parent;

private static Student selected;

public Student() {
    super(new GridLayout());
    addMouseListener(this);
}

public void setParent(JPanel parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
    parent.setBackground(Color.white);
}

public void setCheckBox(JCheckBox box) {
    this.box = box;
}
public void setName(JLabel name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setId(JLabel id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setPoints(JLabel points) {
    this.points = points;
}

public void setForm(JLabel form) {
    this.form = form;
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if(name.getText().equals(" Student")) {
        parent.setBackground(new Color(200,200,255));
        return;
    }
    parent.setBackground(new Color(255,255,190));
    setSelected(this);
    DataPanel.refresh();
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    if(name.getText().equals(" Student")) {
        parent.setBackground(new Color(200,200,255));
        return;
    }
    if(this == getSelected()) {
        parent.setBackground(new Color(255,255,190));
    } else {
    parent.setBackground(new Color(230,230,255));
    }
```

}

```
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    if(name.getText().equals(" Student")) {
        parent.setBackground(new Color(200,200,255));
        return;
    }
    if(this == getSelected()) {
        parent.setBackground(new Color(255,255,210));
    } else {
    parent.setBackground(Color.white); 
    }
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

}

public static Student getSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public static void setSelected(Student selected) {
    Student.selected = selected;
}
```

}

Thanks for your help in advance, and tell me if you require more information...

Oh, and by the way, pay no heed to the actual data, it is just there for testing purposes :)

EDIT: The problem only arises when I add the `parent` (JPanel) to the DataPanel, not     `contents` (JPanel).

Comment: *"The reason why I do not use JTable is because it does not please my aesthetic needs."*  Use a different PLAF.

Comment: I did, however, I decided still to not use it.

Comment: `parent.add("West", box);`  Don't use magic numbers.  Better is `parent.add(box, BorderLayout.WEST);` best is `parent.add(box, BorderLayout.LINE_START);`

Comment: Alright, but that did nothing to help solve the problem?

Comment: That second picture looks fine, isn't your code working in that picture, more than one line is being added to the GUI?

Comment: Yes, sorry, the second picture is the one that works, first one not so...

Comment: *"Alright, but that did nothing to help solve the problem?"*  But that is not a question (even though you threw in a '?').  In any case, that is why my comment was not an answer.  Answers are for solutions, comments are for ..everything else.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: Thanks for teaching my how to structure my code correctly. I still have a long way to go in my Java career...

Comment: Can you say again what is wrong with your project? The second picture, you say it works, so if you know how to make it work and snapshot the second picture, than what is your question?

Comment: When I try to add a checkbox to the cells it only displays one. The question is how I can make it work with the checkbox's being there, in the cells.

Comment: new GridLayout(data.length,1)), is data.length equal to 5? Are you adding a checkbox before you add 4 labels every time?

Comment: data.length is equal to 36 , and yes for the second question, but I add it to a JPanel called parent alongside the other 4 labels

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
Pretty dumb, actually.

Well, basically, I had the constructor for the JPanel 'parent' **outside** the for loop, so it only created one and added **all** the data into the JPanel. This is why only one showed up.
Thanks to all of you who tried to help me. Sorry.